# Is there any formula for number of divisors of a*b?

Tags: math, integer-arithmetic

Let a and b be two numbers,

Number of divisors of (a) =n1;

Number of divisors of (b) =n2;

how to find the number of divisors of (a*b) by using n1 and n2?

```
   a=15; b=20
   n1=4; //no of divisors of a 
   n2=6; //no of divisors of b
   ans=(a*b); //300
   num_ans=18; // no of divisors of a*b
```

Is there any formula to find it?

Comment: MathExchange might be a better place for such tricky stuff ;-)  http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [Mathematics.SE]

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine the number of divisors of the product of two numbers if all you know is the number of divisors of each number.

Example:
2 and 4 have two and three divisors, respectively. Their product, 8, has four divisors.
5 and 9 have two and three divisors, respectively. Their product, 45, has six divisors.

Both of these number pairs have the same number of individual divisors, but their products have different divisors.

Comment: What about for consecutive numbers. As it worked for 20 and 21.

Comment: @sridhar3525: two consecutive numbers are relatively prime, which is the simple case where numbers of divisors multiply.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can infer some information about the answer.

The bounds on the number of divisors of `ans` is `[max(n1,n2),n1 * n2]` (which is [6,24], for 20 and 21).

It's fairly easy to see how this comes about (at least for smaller numbers), by generating the divisors of 420 from the divisors of 20 and 21.

The divisors of 20 are the column headers, the divisors of 21 are the row headers. The cells contain the result of `col_header * row_header` for that row and column.

```
        1    2    4     5    10    20
     +----+----+----+-----+-----+-----|
   1 |  1 |  2 |  4 |   5 |  10 |  20 |
   3 |  3 |  6 | 12 |  15 |  30 |  60 |
   7 |  7 | 14 | 28 |  35 |  70 | 140 |
  21 | 21 | 42 | 84 | 105 | 210 | 420 |
```

Unfortunately, 20 and 21 are a special case, as they are relatively prime. Other combinations result in duplicate values in the cells.

For example, the table for 15 and 20 looks like this:

```
        1    3     5    15 
     +----+----+-----+-----|
   1 |  1 |  3 |   5 |  15 |
   2 |  2 |  6 |  10 |  30 |
   4 |  4 | 12 |  20 |  60 |
   5 |  5 | 15 |  25 |  75 |
  10 | 10 | 30 |  50 | 150 |
  20 | 20 | 60 | 100 | 300 |
```

The numbers 5,10,15,20,30 and 60 appear multiple times, so we can't simply take the number of cells in the table as the number of divisors. The number of unique values in the table does equal the number of divisors (18), which falls within the interval [6,24].

This can give you a ball-park estimate on the complexity of getting the answer, the algorithm for which is essentially generating all of the divisors, discarding duplicates.

Comment: I made a careless mistake in factorization that yielded me different value 32. 420=(2^2)*(3^1)*(5^1)*(7^1). Number of divisors is 3*2*2*2=24, your explanation was very clear. Thank You.

Comment: @sridhar3525 No problem, it happens to everyone. Wolfram Alpha is a great resource for double-checking stuff like this. That being said, I've forgotten to double check and stuck my foot in my mouth often enough :) . You may want to edit your question and put the correct value in.

Comment: Something seems wrong to me here. As a different example, let a=2 and b=2. Both have two divisors, 1 and 2. Their product has three divisors. 1, 2, and 4.

Comment: @Morgen I have change the case dude. 15 n 20. It is not working in this case. May be its working for consecutive numbers, like for 20 n 21.

Comment: @sridhar3525 Looks like I made a careless mistake :) I'll update the answer.